# Extjs listener not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

The listener is not working. Please check (i am new to extjs). 
It's working on the [website](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/quick_start/handling_events.html) from which I am learning but in my local, it's not working.

Please check the issue. (Listener in inside the items on Line 9).

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
                //xtype: 'tabpanel',
                renderTo: Ext.getElementById('helloWorldPanel'),
                items: [{
                    title: 'Employee Directory',
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    //iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
                    listeners: {
                        itemtap: function () {
                            console.log('item tap!');
                        }
                    },
                    store: {
                        data: [{
                            "firstName": "Jean",
                            "lastName": "Grey",
                            "officeLocation": "Lawrence, KS",
                            "phoneNumber": "(372) 792-6728"
                        }, {
                            "firstName": "Phillip",
                            "lastName": "Fry",
                            "officeLocation": "Lawrence, KS",
                            "phoneNumber": "(318) 224-8644"
                        }, {
                            "firstName": "Peter",
                            "lastName": "Quill",
                            "officeLocation": "Redwood City, CA",
                            "phoneNumber": "(718) 480-8560"
                        }]
                    },
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'First Name', dataIndex: 'firstName', flex: 1
                    }, {
                        text: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'lastName', flex: 1
                    }, {
                        text: 'Phone Number', dataIndex: 'phoneNumber', flex: 1
                    }]
                }, {
                    title: 'About Sencha',
                    //iconCls: 'x-fa fa-info-circle'
                }]
            })
        });
```

Comment: Are you working on web application or mobile application?
because which link you saw is for morden toolkit which is for mobile application.

Comment: I am working on web application. @D.V

Comment: Answer updated.Try that. 
Actually you see Mordern toolkit but you should see classic toolkit.

Comment: Are you using the modern toolkit or the classic toolkit?

Comment: @AnkushKapoor use **itemclick** instead of **itemtap** [click to see example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2689).